# Can I combine batteries and a transformer to power a device at same time?

Tags: power-supply, batteries, dc, ac-dc, ups

Particularly i want to buy this smart lock tuya X2 (dont know if exactly the same of the link, just for reference) [link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B088Z7DTVQ) and a I want to get the more possible rid of the preoccupation of getting batteries out of power. (its says 13month of batteries life, welp, not enough for me haha xd)

It uses 4 batteries AAA 1.5V, and I was wondering if there is a way to power it with wall power throw an AC to DC transformer like this one [link](https://www.dvdoverseas.com/ss105-universal-ac-dc-power-adapter) at the same time that the batteries, so in case the power goes out, the batteries continue working (kind of an UPS).

I was thinking of connecting the batteries (I’m assuming they are on series) and the transformer with 6 V in parallel, but I'm guessing that cant be so simple and it would need some electronics (how would it be?), also may influence if the batteries are or not rechargeable.

And yeah, I suppose that the easy way is connect only the transformer with 6 V to the lock and the transformer to an UPS. But i was curious if there is a "light" way using the AAA batteries and the transformer and maybe some electronics.

Comment: Does it work on rechargeable batteries? If yes, replace your batteries with rechargeable ones and hook a battery charger suitable for the type in parallel.

Comment: The second answer (with the relay) is the one I'd use as the lock can cope with losing power briefly while it switches over to the batteries.

Comment: @Finbarr looks like that might be my answer, could you share the pieces you used? I am not an expert to decide which ones to use

Comment: I didn't use anything, it's someone else's answer. But pretty much any relay with 6V coil and a changeover contact rated for at least 1A will do the job.

Answer (score 2):

> its says 13month of batteries life

Dry cells (really, any battery) discharge by themselves over time.  Unless you're getting super-premium dry cells *and* you're trusting, you should probably change them out once a year anyway.